# Read one file and rewrite to another, dropping the first column

Tags: python, pandas

Reading a ;-separated csv-file in an attempt to rewrite it to another csv, separated by ",", the result ends up delivering an additional column as the very first with all the rows counting from 0 to n. How do I leave that new column out?

I import pandas, define the df to read with delimiter=";" (because the file to be read is already in separate columns), then I define "df.to_csv" to rewrite to a new csv-file, separated with commas, i.e. each row is one long string of data.

```
 import pandas as pd

 df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\jcst\\Desktop\\Private\\Python data\\old_file.csv", delimiter=";", encoding='cp1252', error_bad_lines=False)

print(df.columns)

df.to_csv("C:\\Users\\jcst\\Desktop\\Private\\Python data\\new_file.csv", sep=",")
```

The code runs fine, but the result in new_file.csv looks as follows:

```
,data,data,data,....
0,data,data,data,....
1,data,data,data,....
2,data,data,data,....
3,data,data,data,....
4,data,data,data,....
…
11,625,data,data,data,....
```

So, I need to know how to rewrite the code to avoid the leftmost column, counting ,0 , 1, 2,...., 11,625. How do I do that?

Thx, in advance

Comment: index = False ?

Comment: `df.to_csv(yourpath, index=False)`

Comment: Excellent, it worked (of course, it did!)...now I know why I love this blog...;o)))) - thx

Answer (score 1):

Tell the exporter not to export the index:

```
df.to_csv("...", index=False)
```